# Difference between in and for in perfect tense with duration

Tags: prepositions, present-perfect, adverbial-phrases

Compare the following sentences:

> I have lived here for 10 years. **[a]**
>
> I have lived here *on and off* for 10 years. **[b]**
>
> I have lived here *every summer* for 10 years. **[c]**

As I know, the period of time expressed by **for** in **[a]** indicates that the **living** situation lasts **AS LONG AS** 10 years and there is no vacancy or gap during this period of time.

However, in both **[b]** and **[c]**, there are definitely blank space in the period of 10 years that I **didn't** live here. So, Is it better, I think, to change the preposition **for** to **in** in these 2 sentences? We therefore have the following two alternative sentences:

> I have lived here *on and off* in the past 10 years. **[1b]**
>
> I have lived here *every summer* in the past 10 years. **[1c]**

Comment: "for" sounds more idiomatic to me. "in" isn't wrong, it just doesn't seem as natural.

Comment: I don't find _I have lived here every summer_ idiomatic. I would say _I have spent every summer here for the past 10 years_. If you only spend part of the year in a place, you don't live there.

Comment: @Kate Good point. You _can_ of course live in a place for less than a year. It's the iterative aspect 'spending part of the year' demands that makes the sentence improbable. But not impossible. Some people do have different homes and could well establish patterns. But then I think they'd find a better way to express this.

Answer (score 3):

No. **In** is not better – it is worse.

Firstly:

**For** indicates a total duration that can be either continuous* or continual**

**For** = from X to/until Y. If Y is not defined, Y = the present.

*MW: : marked by uninterrupted extension in space, time, or sequence
*The batteries provide enough power for up to five hours of **continuous** use.*

**2. : recurring in steady, usually rapid, succession
*a history of **continual** invasions.*

Secondly:

In the example sentences, *“on and off / every summer”* is a free modifier – it modifies the main clause, which is "I have lived here."

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the predicate. I follow [McCawley's analysis of the senses of the present Perfect construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/53188/15299)

The predicate in (a) is a **Universal** Perfect predicate, a predicate which

- "describes an ongoing continuous situation still true or relevant".

The predicates in (b) and (c), however, are not Universal, but **Existential**, predicates which

- "describe at least a single occurrence of some potentially important event."

An example  is

- *I have read that book 5 times.*

Of course, reading a book takes time, and doing it 5 times takes even longer; but these are treated as events in an unspecified past time, so the Perfect is OK.

As for the prepositions, they depend on the predicate, too. Active predicates can either have an endpoint (*walk to the grocery*) or be endpoints (*arrive*) or have no endpoint (*walk, run*).

*For* as a time preposition occurs with no-endpoint predicates

- *He ran for an hour; he's been showering for a half-hour.*

but not with predicates like *arrive* or *climb the hill*.

- **He has arrived for an hour; she has climbed the hill for an hour*

*For* defines the **outer** time segment in which the predicate is interpreted;
*in* defines the time it takes to achieve an endpoint

- *He has eaten 83 hotdogs in/(*for) 6 minutes and 34 seconds.*
- *He has eaten hotdogs for decades.*

Answer (score 0):

> I lived here on and off **in** the past ten years.
>
> I have lived here on and off in the past ten years.

*At some time during* the past decade, I lived here intermittently. It might have been only for a few years, maybe five to seven years ago. Or it might have been for the whole ten years. The extent is not clear and unambiguous.

The present perfect version intimates that you are still living there now, intermittently.

NOTE: Compare a question you might encounter on an application for automobile insurance: *Have you had any accidents **in** the past five years?*   The insurance company wants to know if that ever happened during the five-year period.  You could answer, *No, **for** five years now, I've been accident-free*.

> I lived here on and off **for** the past ten years.

I lived here *intermittently* for *pretty much every year* in the past ten years, certainly throughout the period albeit with gaps. Perhaps I was away at college for four of those years and came home during the summers, and then got a job as a tennis instructor at a mountain resort so I was away all summer for a few years, and then after that I got a job where I had to be flying around the country and was away from home most of the time but this was nonetheless my "permanent address"  even though I didn't sleep here more than a few days a month.